# Format Labels in Vaadin Charts

Tags: vaadin, string-formatting, vaadin-charts

I'm trying to create a pie chart with Vaadin Charts.

This piece of code adds nice labels to the chart, but two digits after the decimal point t would be enough.

```
 dataLabels.setFormatter("''+ this.point.name +': '+ this.percentage +' %'");
```

[image: See here picture of current chart.]

Any ideas how to print just two digits after the decimal point?

I already tried

```
dataLabels.setFormatter("''+ this.point.name +': '+ this.percentage%02.2f +' %'");
```

and

```
dataLabels.setFormat("{this.percentage:%02.2f}");
```

Comment: I haven't used the charts yet but the last attempt seems correct according to the Vaadin book. Perhaps you can also try [using a javascript function to format the values](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/charts.configuration.html#charts.configuration.format.formatter)

Comment: I also tried to use a function:
`dataLabels.setFormatter("function() {return String.format(\"%02d\", this.percentage) + ' %';}");`
However it is unfortunately not working :(

Answer (score 4):

If you use `setFormat` you shouldn't use `this`:

```
dataLabels.setFormat("{point.name}: {percentage:%02.2f}%");
```

And if you want to use `setFormatter` use the `toFixed()` Javascript function:

```
dataLabels.setFormatter("'' + this.point.name + ': ' + this.percentage.toFixed(2) + '%'");
```